# reading char by char

Tags: c++

my question is a little bit strange, but how is it possible to read some string from keyboard char by char without using `scanf()` and `getchar()` only by using `operator<<`, for example I want to change every letter `a` which I read by `*` thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char c;
std::string output;


while(std::cin >> c)
{
   if(c == 'a')
      c = '*';

   output += c;

}
```

Comment: The `push_back()` method can be replaced by concatenation:  `output += c;`.  This may be more natural since it is an append.

Comment: Good call.  I've been stuck in C land for too long.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your purposes, you may find it adequate to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

char c;

std::cin >> std::noskipws;

while (std::cin >> c)
    std::cout << c == 'a' ? '*' : c;
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/ for further details of noskipws, which is crucial as otherwise operator>> will skip over spaces, tabs and newlines until it finds other characters to put in 'c', resulting in all the aforementioned whitespace characters being removed from your output.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing out to a type of char.

```
char cReadFromStream;

stream >> cReadFromStream;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.  [`operator <<` uses cooked inputs.](http://www.minich.com/education/wyo/cplusplus/cplusplusch10/getfunction.htm)

However, if you really meant you are looking for a solution using C++ iostreams and not C stdio functions, then use `cin.get()` which is the C++ iostreams equivalent to `getchar`.